# C++: Splicing a String within cin Overload

Tags: c++, c-strings, complex-numbers

I am trying to splice a `cin>> string;` which should be a complex number.

I am working within the class Complex, which deals with complex numbers.

I'm having a hard time splicing the string into separate components so I can arrange each substring and convert them into relevant doubles that correspond to imaginary or realpart.

When I run the code there is an error with how I am finding the string I think, it appears to be out of bounds.

This is the header and the definition of my function, overloading `>>`.

**Header:**

```
friend istream& operator >>(istream& inputStream,  Complex& amt);
```

**Definition:**

```
istream& operator >>(istream& inputStream, Complex& amt){

    cout<<"Please enter your complex number: ";
    std::string str;
    inputStream >> str;
    //need different parts of string. imaginary, real, operand, 'i', and beginning sign.


    std::size_t pos = str.rfind('-'|'+');

    std::string str2 = str.substr(pos);     // str2 = imaginarypart

    if(str2.back()=='i'){
        str2.erase( str2.end()-1 );
    }

    if(str2[0]=='+'){
        str2.erase( str2.begin()-1 );
    }

    //str remains with realpart
    return inputStream;
}
```

Comment: Is the input format `(+|-| )a(+|-)bi` absolutely required? Or would you settle for something simpler, as long as you can input complex number values?

Comment: I am working off of this:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/                              Must be in real# (operand) imaginary# so {-3.3+5.3i}.

Comment: Also, I believe `str.rfind('-'|'+')` is not doing what you think it is: it's actually searching backwards for `'/'`.

Comment: Hmm, really? I tried || to signify boolean or, but the compiler indicated I needed only | due to it being a bit comparison.

Comment: Yes, `string::rfind` can only search for one character or one substring per call. Here, you're passing it a character whose value is the result of binary ORing `'-'` and `'+'`. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind

Comment: For "find the last occurrence of either `'+'` or `'-'`", use [`find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of)

Comment: i will use this! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're merely looking for a way to input complex numbers, in any suitable format, I'm proposing a way simpler solution, using `std::complex` from the standard library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt

Something like:

```
#include <complex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool
inputComplexNumber (std::istream& is, std::complex<double>& c)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter your complex number: ";

    is >> c;

    return is.good();
}

int
main ()
{
    std::complex<double> c;

    if (inputComplexNumber(std::cin, c))
        std::cout << c.real() << (c.imag() > 0 ? "+" : "") << c.imag() << "i" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Bad complex number." << std::endl;
}
```

Sample runs:

```
Please enter your complex number: (-69.1, 42.2)            
-69.1+42.2i

Please enter your complex number: blah
Bad complex number.
```

If you really do want to stick to the pretty format on input, then I would  recommend that you write a little grammar for this mini-language, and derive proper scanning and parsing functions from that. That's a bit of work, but it's well worth it in the end.

Comment: This code is for an assignment so I think the developing my own scanning/parsing would help because I would ultimately be adding, multiplying, ect for the complex numbers. Importing from std:: may not fulfill the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: Likely not, indeed... Oh well :)